# Can I add bullet points or line breaks in inspect element

Tags: php, html, web-inspector

I am wondering if its possible to add bullet points in front of words and add new lines while using inspect element with chrome. For example, I have a webpage snippet of text below:

Grass 
Trees

But I want it to look like (dont mind the small spaces added between):

- Grass
- Trees
- Garden
- Pool

Note all I did was put bullets in front of the words and add a few more words ON A NEW LINE.

All Im asking is would it be possible to make this change strictly inside of the Inspect Element tool? I have tried the obvious by first adding a br tag tags but I dont know if its even possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have two options; using `<ul>` and `<li>`, or by manually adding the bullet character: •

If you right click on an element, you can choose "Edit as HTML" and you will be able to edit the raw HTML of that element and anything beneath it. If you insert HTML tags into a string that you're editing, the inspector will escape them.

`<ul>` stands for Unordered List (bullets), and `<li>` stands for List Item, which designates that anything inside it will be treated as a separate entry to the list. [More here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)

Alternatively, if they're already spaced how you desire, you can manually insert the bullet character by pasting it in, or using the [escape sequence.](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256b280015193f87256c47007456e7)